# Convert an integer's binary data to float

Tags: c++, floating-point

Lets say I have an integer:

```cpp
unsigned long long int data = 4599331010119547059;
```

Now I want to convert this data to a double. I basically want to change the type, but keep the bits exactly as they were. For the given example, the float value is `0.31415926536`.

How can I do that in C++? I saw some methods using Union but many advised against using this approach.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the greater goal you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @scohe001 reading floating point numbers from a file. first, the data is converted to an int, and if required, this int needs to be converted to a float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since C++20, you can use `std::bit_cast`:

```
std::bit_cast<double>(data)
```

Prior to C++20, you can use `std::memcpy`:

```
double d;
static_assert(sizeof d == sizeof data);
std::memcpy(&d, &data, sizeof d);
```

Note that result will vary depending on floating point representation (IEEE-754 is ubiquitous though) as well as whether floating point and integer types have the same endianness.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the question on its face value (assuming you have a valid reason to do this!) this is the only proper way of doing this in current C++ standard:

```
int i = get_int(); 
float x;
static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int), "!!!");
memcpy(&x, &i, sizeof(x));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
float f = reinterpret_cast<float&>(data);
```

For your value, I don't get 0.314... but that's how you could do it.

Comment: Welcome to the Undefined Behavior land, where everything is possible and nothing is certain!

Comment: @SergeyA reinterpret_cast is not undefined.

Comment: @n.m. the cast isn't, but accessing the `float` object that does not exist through the reference is UB.

Comment: @n.m. cast is well-defined. Accessing the float is not. Granted, the code in the answer **does not** access the float, but in the context of the question, it is reasonable to assume that later access is expected.